# How to add DynamoDB IAM Role to EKS Worker Nodes in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to write to DynamoDB from my worker nodes in EKS. I'm currently attaching an IAM Role Policy that grants full access to DynamoDB. Is this the correct way to approach this problem? Requests from my application currently hang, which I'm assuming has something to do with my nodes not having the correct permissions.

Here is my current setup in Terraform

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "worker-node" {
  name = "worker-node"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "worker-node-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.worker-node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "worker-node-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.worker-node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "worker-node-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.worker-node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "worker-node-AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
  role       = aws_iam_role.worker-node.name
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "node-private" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
  node_group_name = "node-group-private"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.worker-node.arn
  subnet_ids      = [aws_subnet.private-1.id, aws_subnet.private-2.id]
  instance_types = ["t2.micro"]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 3
    min_size     = 1
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.worker-node-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.worker-node-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.worker-node-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.worker-node-AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess,
  ]
}
```

Comment: This gives your entire node group access to DynamoDB. Wouldn't you just want to have the pods have the permissions to do this?